# (React Native) Retrieving next value in JSON file when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mobile

Let's say I have a local JSON file (./movies.json) structured as

```
{ "movies": [ 
    { "title" : "Terminator", "year" :  "1984", "genre" : "Action" },
    { "title" : "Jumanji", "year" : "2017", "genre" : "Adventure"},
    { "title" : "Incredibles 2", "year" : "2017", "genre" : "Animation"}]
}
```

Whenever a button is clicked, I want to output, for example, a Text Field with 
Terminator --> Jumanji --> Incredibles 2, in order. 
I also want to be able to access all three of "title", "movie", "genre" (in separate text fields) in order, when the button is clicked.

This is what I have so far, to get just the titles of the movies in order.It doesn't work, because I don't think I'm pulling from the JSON file correctly.

```
import jsonData from "./movies.json";

export default class Movies extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
      this.state = {
         results:{
         titles: [],
         years: [], 
         genres: []
       }
     }
  };
}
componentDidMount = () => {
  // const data = json.stringify(jsonData)  I think this line is not correct 
  this.setState({ data })
}
render () { 
  titles_list = this.state.results.titles.map((item) => {
  return (
      <View key={item.title}>
        <Text>
          {item.title}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
 });
return (
  <View>
    {titles_list}
  </View>
);
}
}
```

I'm not sure how to implement a button so that when it is pressed, the next title/year/genre is shown. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the index of the array in a state variable.
First of all, I will assume that you passed that json into `state.movies`

So initialize it as follows:

```
   this.state = {
     movies: [], // where the movies are
     displayIndex: 0 // This will be the index that you show
   }
```

When you press your button call a function that will call either of the following functions:

```
moveForward(){
  this.setState({displayIndex: this.state.displayIndex++})
}
moveBack(){
  this.setState({displayIndex: this.state.displayIndex--})
}
```

Then when you display the fields under your render function grab the object you need as follows:

```
render(){
   const movieData = this.state.movies[this.state.displayIndex];
   ....//Do the display logic here
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem I'm having now is I'm not sure how to pull that movies JSON local file and set just the  titles, genres, years in the lists (like the movies: [] you created). Could you explain that part?

Comment: You going to need to have something hosting the json, or simply have the json hardcoded in the `js`. If its hosted you will need something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios to pull it. If its hard-coded, simply have the component load it with `.setState` or pass into the props of the component (the latter is more inline with the "react-way")

Comment: import jsonData from "./data.json";
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.setState({ jsonData })
} - Would this be the right way?